# Angular Conditional Validation with Pre populated Data

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms, angular-validation

I want to validate a field where data may or maynot be auto populated in a required field .So I have basically two conditions to validate:

a. If no data is present, wait for touch, then display error ie. required,min,max errors.

b. If data is present, just display error, don't wait for touch.
     My `ng-if` looks like:

```
ng-if="(!$ctrl.formName.address1.$length && $ctrl.formName.address1.$touched)
       || ($ctrl.formName.address1.$length)
       || $ctrl.formName.address1.$invalid"
```

address1 is my field name.

My Input box looks like below:

```
<input
    id="address-form-address1"
    class="form-control text-uppercase"
    name="address1"
    ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled"
    ng-maxlength="{{::$ctrl.INPUT_VALUES.guest.address.max}}"
    ng-minlength="{{::$ctrl.INPUT_VALUES.guest.address.min}}"
    ng-model="$ctrl.addressData.address1"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
    ng-pattern="$ctrl.REGEX.alphanumericSpecial"
    ng-required="$ctrl.required"
    type="text"
>
```

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the problem, display the control:

```
<form name="$ctrl.formName">
    <input
        id="address-form-address1"
        class="form-control text-uppercase"
        name="address1"
        ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled"
        ng-maxlength="{{::$ctrl.INPUT_VALUES.guest.address.max}}"
        ng-minlength="{{::$ctrl.INPUT_VALUES.guest.address.min}}"
        ng-model="$ctrl.addressData.address1"
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
        ng-pattern="$ctrl.REGEX.alphanumericSpecial"
        ng-required="$ctrl.required"
        type="text"
    >
</form>

{{ $ctrl.formName.address1 | json }}
```

This should quickly show what is happening and should help.